# How do I upgrade to the latest Java 7 while not losing my existing Java dependencies and add-ons?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, updates, package-management, java

```
$ uname -a
Linux X51 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:56:25 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

I have above versions, which have important stable setup (for my own application):

- Unfortunately i was working always with Java 1.6 as shown.
- But now discovered that many-things are not working because of that version issue.
- I want to remove the:

a) old java completely (safely)

b) switch to new, install openjdk-7 64-bit (safely)

Is it a better idea to simply apply `apt-get remove openjdk*.` ?

Or

what else would be smarter and safer way? 
(to avoid not losing many other dependencies just only to remove openjdk-6)

**Follow up:**

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.3) (7u9-2.3.3-0ubuntu1~12.10.1)

$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for sun: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what else would be smarter and safer way? (to avoid not losing many other dependencies just only to remove openjdk-6)

The smartest way is to be backward-compatible and **install both of them** (Java 7 is still maturing, I believe.)

Install OpenJDK 7, and whatever else you need, and then use `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to show you the various available `java` binaries and their locations and select a *default* (invoked when you just type `java`).

This lets you still use Java 6 when necessary by simply calling it via the full path to the binary. Replace `java` with `javac`, etc. in `update-alternatives` and set those too.

When you determine that all your code/programs runs stable on 1.7 and want to get rid of 1.6, run `dpkg --list | grep -i openjdk` to find out what packages are installed on your system, before you run something like `apt-get remove openjdk.*`!!